# jenks dsl BuildMonitorView generates a list view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am attempting to generate a buildMonitorView using the jenkins DSL but a ListView is always generated. My DSL is as follows:

```
    private static void generateBuildMonitorView(dslFactory, viewName, viewDescription, viewRegex) {
    dslFactory.buildMonitorView(viewName) {
        description(viewDescription)
        jobs {
            regex(viewRegex)
        }
    }
}
```

When I look at the generated view XML I see the following:

```
    <hudson.model.ListView>
  <owner class="com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder" reference="../../.."/>
  <name>ViewName</name>
  <description>Builds</description>
  <filterExecutors>true</filterExecutors>
  <filterQueue>true</filterQueue>
  <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
  <jobNames>
    <comparator class="hudson.util.CaseInsensitiveComparator"/>
  </jobNames>
  <jobFilters/>
  <columns>
    <hudson.views.BuildButtonColumn/>
    <hudson.views.StatusColumn/>
    <hudson.views.WeatherColumn/>
    <hudson.views.JobColumn/>
    <hudson.views.LastSuccessColumn/>
    <hudson.views.LastFailureColumn/>
    <hudson.views.LastDurationColumn/>
  </columns>
  <includeRegex>^.+-BuildName$</includeRegex>
  <recurse>false</recurse>
</hudson.model.ListView>
```

Looking at github, I see that the BuildMonitorView extends the ListView but does not contain anything to differentiate it from the ListView.

I have the build monitor view plugin installed and enabled so I am assuming that is not the issue as I am able to manually create them. Has anyone generated a BuildMonitorView using the jenkins DSL?

Comment: Your view configuration is fine as you can test on http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com. You should use `BuildMonitorView` as the return value of the function `generateBuildMonitorView`. The issue seems to lie within the usage of this function. Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crasps answer worked. ALso, thanks for pointing out that tool. It is extremely helpful.